# If `Object` is the superlcass of all, why we say Java doesn't have multiple inheritance?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Why a subclass cannot have multiple superclass?

And if multiple inheritance is not possible in Java,  then why a subclass `B`(say) can have a superclass `A`(say) and also has the `Object` class which is the superclass of all classes?

Comment: also duplicates [Multiple inheritance in Java or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14692537/296974).

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

The simplest multiple inheritance is like this:

```
A        B
 \      /
  \    /
   \  /
    C
```

While your example in Java is like this:

```
Object
  |
  |
  |
  A
  |
  |
  |
  B
```

which is multiple levels of single inheritance.