# java and multiple inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

Can we call this code as multiple inheritance ?

```
interface Interface {

    public int alpha = 0;
    public int calculA(int a, int b);
    public int calculB(int a, int b);
}

interface InterfaceA extends Interface {

    public default int calculA(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

interface InterfaceB extends Interface {

    public default int calculB(int a, int b) {
        return a - b;
    }
}

class TestInterface implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {

    public TestInterface() {
        System.out.println(alpha);
        System.out.println(calculA(5, 2));
        System.out.println(calculB(5, 2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestInterface();
    }
}
```

It look like the default keyword permit to have a multiple inheritance.

It is correct or this concept have an another name ?

Thank's

**Edit**

It's not a duplicate of [Are defaults in JDK 8 a form of multiple inheritance in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857832) because this thread talking about the feature called Virtual Extensions.

My question is to ask if my implementation is called *multiple inheritance* or *something else*.

Comment: you can't have implementation in interfaces unless you are using JVM with java 7 and the method is declared static

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are defaults in JDK 8 a form of multiple inheritance in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857832/are-defaults-in-jdk-8-a-form-of-multiple-inheritance-in-java)

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I have Java 8 and this code is correct and it work

Comment: There are different kinds of multiple inheritance. Your code features multiple inheritance of types and behavior (through virtual extension methods) not multiple inheritance of state (which is not possible in Java). [Here](http://www.lambdafaq.org/do-default-methods-introduce-multiple-inheritance-to-java/) is a short article about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java` **doesn't** supports multiple inheritance.

What you are doing is implementing an `interface`. **You can't extend multiple classes in `java` but you can implement multiple interfaces**.

An interface is a reference type and it is similar to class. It is a collection of abstract methods. A class implements an interface, thereby inheriting the abstract methods of the interface. An interface may also contain constants, default methods, static methods, and nested types. Method bodies exist only for default methods and static methods.

A class describes the attributes and behaviors of an object and an interface contains behaviors that a class implements.

For more on `interface`, [click here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Comment: Thank's, I know that. But now, it looks like using default methods in Interface like I do before, permit to have a kind of multiple inheritance. My question is just it is correct to name it like this or differently.

Comment: I wouldn't use the word `multiple inheritance` and `java` in same sentence

Comment: I know all that concepts. And it's why I ask my question here to confirm or not. I know that one of the first Law Of Java is to not have multiple inheritance, but it look like, by my implementation, it's now possible.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

What you have currently done is implement multiple interfaces which is absolutely permittable.

Comment: Right, it is permitable, and it is permitable to implement by default this methods, then you could make multiple inheritance by this way. It looks like at least...